# Google Maps within IF condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I have scenario where Google Map loads on either Longitude and Latitude which comes from database or using Postal code which also comes from database, if the long - lat become null which is not working properly. I am binding long, lat, Pin code values to hidden fields.

The Script is:

```
var lat = $('#<%=hdnLat.ClientID %>').val();
var long = $('#<%=hdnLong.ClientID %>').val();
var add = $('#<%=hdnAddress.ClientID %>').val();
var title = $('#<%=hdnTitle.ClientID %>').val();
var pinCode = $('#<%=hdnPin.ClientID %>').val();

if (!lat == '' || !lat == null) {
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var zoomratio = 15;
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: zoomratio,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
            },
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            }
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);
        var url = "Images/YellowPages/pointer.png";
        var htmlStr = "<div style='border:1px solid #ddd;padding:3px;'>" +
           "<h4 style='margin-top:0;width:200px;line-height:1.25;'>" + title + "</h4>" +
           "<p>" + add + "</p>" +
           "</div>";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: url,
            title: title
        });
        (function (marker, htmlStr) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(htmlStr);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, htmlStr);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
} else {
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9539974, 77.6309395);
        var zoomratio = 8;
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: zoomratio,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            },
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            }
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
    }

    function codeAddress() {

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': pinCode + ', India' }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

The issue is `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` always first sets to the first condition and then jumps to the second condition immediately if there is value in `lat` and `long` variables.

Is there anyway to avoid it or is there any simple method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with the condition

```
if(!lat == '' || !lat == null)
```

that always evaluates to TRUE (because !lat means FALSE)

What you meant to write is:

```
if(lat != '' || lat != null)
```